# Composite function limit and Neighborhood blacked out

Tags: limits

We know that if we suppose $g$ and $f$ are functions that

$$\lim _{x\to a}g(x)=L,\quad 
\lim _{x\to L}f(x)=A$$

and  $g(x)\ne L$ in neighborhood blacked out at $a$, so we can say that
$$\lim _{x\to a}f(g(x))=A.$$

I have a question:
If we delete assumption "$g(x)\ne L$ in neighborhood blacked out at $a$", then why this mathematical theorem is wrong?

Comment: The term "deleted/punctured neighborhood of $a$" is commonly used in place of "neighborhood blacked out at $a$". The statement $\lim_{x\to L} f(x) =A$ does not deal with $x=L$ and hence the behavior of $f(g(x)) $ when $g(x) =L$ can not inferred from the given conditions.